# Which first-order theories have full indiscernible extraction?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

Stable theories have the following useful property, which I will state in a sub-optimal way for simplicity's sake:

> *Fact 1.* If $T$ is $\lambda$-stable for some $\lambda \geq |T|^+$, then for any set of parameters $B$ and subset $A \subset B$ with $|B| > \lambda \geq |A|$, there is an $A$-indiscernible sequence $I \subseteq B$ with $|I| > \lambda$.

NIP theories enjoy a similar but weaker property:

> *Fact 2.* If $T$ is NIP, then for any set of parameters $A$ and any indiscernible sequence $(b_i)_{i < (|T|+|A|)^+}$, there is some $\alpha < (|T|+|A|)^+$ such that $(b_i)_{\alpha \leq i < (|T|+|A|)^+}$ is $A$-indiscernible.

Theories that have 'bounded arity' have something similar to Fact 1, by the Erdős–Rado theorem:

> *Fact 3.* If $T$ has quantifier elimination in a language containing only relation symbols of arity at most $r$, then for any set of parameters $A$ and any set $B$ with $|B| > \beth_{r}(|T|+|A|)$, there is an $A$-indiscernible sequence $I \subseteq B$ with $|I| = (2^{|T|+|A|})^+$.

By contrast, in arbitrary theories and without assuming large cardinals, we only have the following much weaker fact:

> *Fact 4.* For any cardinal $\lambda$, let $\kappa(\lambda) =\beth_{(2^{\lambda})^+}$.
> For any theory $T$, any set of parameters $A$,
> and any sequence $(b_i)_{i<\kappa(|T|+|A|)}$, there is an $A$-indiscernible sequence $(c_j)_{j<\omega}$ such that $\mathrm{tp}(c_{<j}/A)$ is realized in $b_{<\kappa(|T|+|A|)}$ by some increasing tuple of elements for each $j<\omega$.

I have a few questions about the extent to which these kinds of phenomena are characterized. Call a set $X$ *small* if either there is no inaccessible cardinal or $|X|$ is smaller than the first inaccessible cardinal.

Say that a small theory $T$ has *indiscernible extraction* if for every small $\lambda$, there is a small $\kappa$ such that for any sets of parameters $A$ and $B$ with $|A| \leq \lambda$ and $|B| \geq \kappa$, there is an infinite $A$-indiscernible sequence $I \subseteq B$. Say that $T$ has *weak indiscernible extraction* if the same holds with the additional requirement that $B$ is a $\varnothing$-indiscernible sequence.

> **Question 1.** Which theories have indiscernible extraction? Do (small) NIP theories have indiscernible extraction?

We already know that some theories, such as $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself, do not have indiscernible extraction. Moreover, we can build simple theories that fail to have it. For instance, if we take a theory with infinitely many generically chosen predicates of each arity, this will be simple, but we will be able to code the full elementary diagram of $(V_\kappa,\in)$ in a set of parameters.

> **Question 2.** Which theories have weak indiscernible extraction?